# How to add scripts to blog?

Tags: blogger, javascript, syntax-highlighting

I want to add some source code in my blog in Blogger, so I did a search. In the website I found a similar question and in the solutions I found a solution:

1. Copy the following code:

   ```
   <link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
   <link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPerl.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script language='javascript'>
       SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
       SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = 'http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf';
       SyntaxHighlighter.all();
   </script>
   ```
2. Paste it into your Blogger template just above the `</head>` tag.
3. Save the template.
4. Then you can start creating code blocks in your existing or new Blog entries.
5. There are two ways to add a code block using `SyntaxHighlighter`.

Method 1: Using the `script` tag

```
<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: csharp">
<![CDATA[ //Simple Code ]]></script>
```

Method 2: Using the `pre` tag

```
<pre class="brush: csharp">//Simple Code</pre>
```

The problem is that the first method doesn't work and it doesn't display anything, and the second method displays the source code but without the syntax highlighting.

I think there is something which doesn't allow scripts to work in my blog.

So could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have look at this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37830/29140

Answer (score 1):

I tried Method 2, using my Blogger account. I have a fairly complicated template, so I added the scripts just below the title tags in the HTML header.

It worked without any problems for me.

Perhaps you have a setting in your browser that prevents JavaScript from running? I viewed my Blogger post in FireFox.

Keep in mind that each time you load your webpage, it will need to access the developer's website (`http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/`). Instead of hard-linking to his URL, you should fork his scripts from GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It's not the browser which prevents JS from running because I tried it in other browsers, one more thing could you please tell me how can fork those scripts from GirHub ?